# How to read character spacial file using file parsing in linux?

Tags: c

ex: - This is how I am opening a file

```
   if ((fp = fopen("/dev/kmsg", "r")) == NULL) {
            printf("opeaning file /dev/kmsg");
   }
```

Comment: USe `perror` on failure of `fopen`

Comment: You can use fscanf or manually read, just like normal files

Comment: Do not only use the title to describe your problem.

Comment: @Badda Titles should write the most relevant stuff about the question so we know at a glance whether we may be able to answer or not

Comment: @PaulStelian Yes, his title is good, but the problem is not described in the post. It should be explained and described in the OP - title is not a self-sufficient explanation

Comment: the real problem with the question is that it doesn't show what has been tried so far and how it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Once `fopen` succeeded you can use usual parsing techniques on it, even if the file descriptor is a character device or a [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html) (or even many pseudo-files under `/proc/` like `/proc/self/maps`, see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)...). Generally such a file descriptor might be unseekable (e.g. [lseek(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/lseek.2.html) would fail).

You may want to read line by line (using `fgets` or [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html)) and parse every line e.g. with [sscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sscanf.3.html) or otherwise. If using `sscanf` (or `fscanf` ...) be sure to check the return count. Sometimes using `%n` could be helpful